# jQuery datepicker set to null

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a problem with setting a date to `Null` in my table. I have datepicker that is by default blank (and when I save, it return to DB as `0000-00-00` but I want to set as `Null`. In column option I set default to `Null`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class='col-sm-2'>
Datum kontakta
<div class="form-group">
<div class='input-group date' id='datum_kontakta_picker'>
<input name="datum_kontakta" type='text' class="form-control" value="<?php echo $values['datum_kontakta']?>" />
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and script that for datepicker:

```
<script>
    $('#datum_kontakta_picker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',   
    }, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
      }
    );
</script>
```

How can I save `Null` to the table when datepicker is empty?

I try to set `defaultDate: null` but did not help.

Comment: 1) what's the data type in the sql db?  (assuming null, just checking)   2) what's the data type of the field/variable in the middle tier (looks like php here?).   If it's a date type, it might be that the variable doesn't allow nulls so is defaulting to 0000-00-00

Comment: Data type in DB is `Date` with sellected `Null` to be default. In my PHP input field is `text`. Should i change   from text to something else?

Answer (score 6):

It is recommended that you should set minimum DateTime value in the table of your DataBase instead of null for dates.

Whereas if you want to store in string format, then you can use :

```
$('#datum_kontakta_picker').val() ? $('#datum_kontakta_picker').val() : null;
```

Comment: i need `Null` because in another query i use counter ad it will count if date is 0000-00-00, i know i can set to != 0000-00-00 but i think this is not good idea, is it? Where do i put `$('#datum_kontakta_picker').val() ? $('#datum_kontakta_picker').val() : null;` sorry i am learning jquery - begginer

Comment: the place from you are posting the datepicker value to server side to store in table, and add that counter code too.

Comment: well i think it is not the problem in jquery, i just tested to save that field without datepicker and maualy set value to `""` and it still save in DB as `0000-00-00`. Jst to update you all, on inset row into table it will set to `null` becouse default is set to `null`, but on update it save as `0000-00-00`

Comment: then in server side you must have declared the data type to DateTime or else in DataBase table design column may be set to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

try defaultdate blank

```
defaultDate: ''
```

try somthing like this also

```
 $('#datum_kontakta_picker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',  
    minDate: 0,            
        }
function(start, end, label) {
        console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
      }
    }).val('');
```

Comment: try this, did not work. Just to be sure I am putting defaultDate after `format: 'YYY/DD/MM',` ??

Comment: this work for me once try before format: 'YYY/DD/MM',