# PHP mysql query that does not count 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have 4 dates that I need to count, the first date needs to be equal to $_POST and other 3 should not count `0000-00-00` as a date.

I tried this query:

```
$sql_list = "SELECT Agent,count(datum_obrade) as obrada, 
count(datum_kontakta) as kontakti,
count(datum_vracanja) as zadrzani,
count(datum_terminacije) as terminacija from wb_base WHERE datum_obrade = '".$_POST["From"]."' 
group by Agent";
```

The problem is that `count()` will count `0000-00-00` as a date (my column is PHPMyAdmin is set as DATE)
I notice if I manually set date to `NULL` in DB the query wont count it, but the problem is that my jquery date picker won't return `NULL` into db if it is empty. I also asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440304/jquery-datepicker-set-to-null)

So how do I set this query to count all that dates that are not 0000-00-00. If I add `AND` after `WHERE` then the query needs to match 3 criteria. Also if I use `OR` it will still count wrong.

Comment: Pull the full data array from the database and use array_diff to get what is not "0000-00-00" and count that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sql_list = "SELECT Agent,count(datum_obrade) as obrada, 
count(case when datum_kontakta>0 then 1 end) as kontakti,
count(case when datum_vracanja>0 then 1 end) as zadrzani,
count(case when datum_terminacije>0 then 1 end) as terminacija from wb_base WHERE datum_obrade = '".$_POST["From"]."' 
group by Agent";
```

The `case` clause filters out all entries that are not `>0`. In these cases a `null` value is sent to the `count()` function where it will *not* score. So only "valid" dates are counted in the end.

Comment: well, this actually working, thank you. I never use `case` so what this do here. It checks if any count i greater than 0? What is `then 1 end` statement?

Comment: @rtstorm `end` is part of the `case` syntax, it shows where the end of the expression is. `then 1` is the value that's returned by the expression when the condition is matched.

Comment: @rtstorm See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case for the syntax of `CASE`.

Comment: @rtstorm The `case` statements used have an implied `ELSE NULL`; so those that don't pass the WHEN condition "count" as null.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Agent`
  , COUNT(NULLIF(datum_obrade, '0000-00-00')) as obrada
  , COUNT(NULLIF(datum_kontakta, '0000-00-00')) as kontakti
  , COUNT(NULLIF(datum_vracanja, '0000-00-00')) as zadrzani
  , COUNT(NULLIF(datum_terminacije, '0000-00-00')) as terminacija 
FROM wb_base 
WHERE datum_obrade = ?
GROUP BY `Agent`
;
```

These NULLIF() functions will convert values matching '0000-00-00' to null, and otherwise use the values that do not.